# "Operand of postfix '!' should have optional type; type is 'CGVector'"

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I'm using Xcode 6 with Swift and I'm getting the error "Operand of postfix '!' should have optional type; type is 'CGVector'" on my code saying I have to remove a ! however when I do I get the error "Value of optional type 'CGVector?' not unwrapped; did you mean to use '!' or '?'?" which forces me to add it again.

I'm not sure what to do, here's the line that produces the error, the problem is with the property "velocity":

```
if(Utils.getNetVec(physicsBody?.velocity!, gravity: gravity, signs: true).dy > CGFloat(0)) {
```

How can I get around this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you put parenthesis around `physicsBody?.velocity` then it works

```
if(Utils.getNetVec((physicsBody?.velocity)!, gravity: gravity, signs: true).dy > CGFloat(0)) {
```

This is because `velocity` itself isn't an optional, but is made optional because its accessed through optional chaining. The optional needs to be unwrapped, but just putting `!` after isn't good enough because it binds to `velocity`. Adding the parenthesis causes `!` to be applied to the result of the optional chaining expression.

Comment: Thanks, for anyone with the same problem note that it could also be fixed by unwrapping physicsBody

Comment: Checking/unwrapping `physicsBody` first is indeed probably a better idea.